# Is there any SEO value from an external link that passes through a 302 redirect on the external site?

Tags: seo, redirects, links, 302-redirect

Our local Chamber of Commerce has an incoming link to us, but they are using an internal ASP page to process the link and using a 302 redirect to send that page to our site. So our anchor text on their home page actually links to an internal page on ***their*** site that then 302 redirects to the URL passed to it.

Am I right in assuming that none of our anchored keyword text link juice is being passed and that this redirected link is much less valuable to us than a direct link? Is it even valuable at all, from an SEO standpoint, if performed in this manner?

Answer (score 1):

Matt Cutts has said that Google will follow redirects up to a certain point so these links will have some value. There will be some loss of PageRank due to the redirect, however.

Comment: I thought that only applied to 301s though. 302 is a temporary redirect so they probably don't pass "link juice".

Comment: I am fairly certain Matt Cutts said Google treats 301s and 302s the same. Now to go and find that link...

Comment: What's your source for saying there's a loss due to the redirect? Does that still apply?

Comment: As stated in the answer, Matt Cutts has stated it in his blog. It still applies. But it doesn't really matter since PR is barely a ranking factor any more.